# how to print the data in proper JSON format that is returning from the JS function in Karate feature

Tags: karate

```
  Scenario: set data within js function Scenario in Karate
    * def doWork =
  """
  function(jsonData) {
   print("json: " , JSON.stringify(jsonData));
 jsonData.programmingLanguage = 'Java'
 jsonData.framework = 'Karate'
 jsonData.array = [1,2,3,4]
   print("json: " , JSON.stringify(jsonData));
return jsonData
  }
  """
    * def jsonRequest = {name: "Karate Test", topic: "API Testing"}
    * def result = doWork(jsonRequest)
    And print "result " + result // this prints data as 19:04:19.661 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] result [object Object]
```

How to print a result variable data in proper JSON format? I tried looking at the documentation but did not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make this change:

```
And print 'result: ', result
```

Don't use a `+` and concatenate strings, use a comma.

This is explained in the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#print